# SSRS Bar Charts - Only Show Data where the MonthName is greater of equal than Today

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

I have a bar chart in SSRS with Category Group as 'MonthName' [January, February etc]. What expression do I use in the filter to show me only those months that are equal or greater than today. Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Claire

Comment: Hi Claire.  I would add a field to your dataset which has the month number as an integer in it.  (using DATEPART ( [YourDate , m ) Then in your SSRS report you can put an expression filter on the chart that says Month >= Month(Today())

Comment: Yes, I have the month number in the dataset already. Will give it a try and let you know. Thank you

Comment: I'm getting error message <value> Value is not an integer number? Added it to the filer on the 'Category Group Properties'

Comment: Will let me put month = 2 OR month IN 2,3,4 etc. but not above?